# How to change get JSON request's URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change the url being called to that retrieves JSON data and populates my form. I want to be able to click on a button and have it change the data in the table to the data from the new url.

I can populate my form with the original url, but can't get an onClick button to change the url it's calling for data.

```
    $.getJSON('https://1sttest.com/' + myFunction function(data) {

    myData.append("<div class='myData' data-aos='fade-down')
```

I want a button to be able to change the $.getJSON url and load the new data as the first set is currently displaying.

Comment: Store the url in a variable, and call `getJSON` with that variable instead of the hardcoded url. Then change the value of the variable with your button click handler.